# NextJS Strict CSP using next/image

Tags: next.js, next.js13, content-security-policy, nextjs-image

I'm trying to implement a strict Content Security Policy in my app and although I don't use any inline styles I was getting a ton of errors for `unsafe-inline` styles.

Inspecting my page on my browser developer's tools in the Elements tab, I noticed that all images had inline styles applied so I realized that Next's `<Image />` component renders out an `<img style="color:transparent;background-size:cover;..." />` with inline styles applied.

Does anyone know if there is an efficient solution for this/how `<Image />` can be used with strict CSP?

Thanks in advance!